# rails and rvm out of whack after npm and bower install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, rvm

I just installed npm `sudo apt-get install npm` and now when I go to terminal and try running my rails application `rails s` I get an error

```
bjorgvin@buntu:~/projects/kladdi$ rails s
-bash: /home/bjorgvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Also, when I do `rvm list` I get the same error

```
bjorgvin@buntu:~/projects/kladdi$ rvm list
-bash: /home/bjorgvin/.rvm/scripts/list: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, if I run rvm -v I get this

```
bjorgvin@buntu:~/projects/kladdi$ rvm -v

rvm 1.23.10 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Something must have happened to my environment because I had a problem with `sudo` as well since I got `can not resolve host buntu` error when I tried using `sudo` but that was fixed when I edited my `hosts` file and added the line `127.0.0.1 buntu`

anyway... can anyone help me get my environment up and running? I checked and `/usr/bin/env` does not exist neither as a file or directory.

I have been using Linux for a few months developing ruby and rails applications but I can not say that I'm fluent in Linux terminology so any help is a appreciated; thank you.

Comment: I got some help from a friend and the first thing he asked was: "what does `env` 
give you?" so I opened a terminal and ran `env` and realised that I needed to reinstall 
by running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils` and this got my `env` working
and when I ran `rails s` **it worked!!** 

So the question becomes **WHY did this happen?**

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/npm/filelist does not have `env` maybe some of the dependencies?